# how communicate or invoke between c# form and vb6.0 form in a application?

Tags: c#, vb6

I have created an application that is c# mdi form, and it dynamic invoke vb6 dll. and the vb6 dll has over several hundred.
how communicate or invoke between c# form and vb6 form?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Interop to call your VB6 code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as long as it is registered for COM.

> COM Interop provides access to existing COM components without requiring that the original component be modified. When you want to incorporate COM code into a managed application, import the relevant COM types by using a COM Interop utility (TlbImp.exe) for that purpose. Once imported, the COM types are ready to use.
>   In addition, COM Interop allows COM developers to access managed objects as easily as they access other COM objects. Again, COM Interop provides a specialized utility (RegAsm.exe) that exports the managed types into a type library and registers the managed component as a traditional COM component.
>   At run time, the common language runtime marshals data between COM objects and managed objects as needed.

I did this while porting a very large VB6 app to C# in stages and can confirm that it works even for complex apps.

Comment: it's appropriate for c# mdi form invoke vb6.0 form? and vb6.0 form invoke other form in parent mdi's form. c# form's buttnon invoke vb6.0 form's control(textbox or button event).

Comment: I didn't work specifically with MDI forms, but we did mix VB6 forms and WinForms successfully.  Create a small proof-of-concept project and try it out.

Comment: could you show me the code for vb6 and c# has been invoked each other?